# Boot Acronis true image and Clonezilla ISO image alone side windows 7 , Ubuntu 14.04.1

Tags: multi-boot, bootloader, grub2

I want to create boot menu it can be boot from my (installed OS) Windows 7 and Ubuntu 14.04.1

I can add Windows 7 alone side Ubuntu in "Grub 2" with "Boot-Repair" but i can't boot Clonezilla and Acronis true image with UNetbootin or other app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clonezilla live USB runs by default completely from your computer's RAM, which makes it very fast, so there's no point to installing Clonezilla on your computer's hard drive. In addition since Clonezilla live USB is portable, the same installation of Clonezilla live USB can be used on multiple computers.

The instructions for making a Clonezilla live USB in Ubuntu can be found in [How to create a bootable Clonezilla USB that works?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/477573/how-to-create-a-bootable-clonezilla-usb-that-works).

You can also create a bootable Acronis live USB by following the instructions on the [Starting Acronis Product from USB Flash Drive](https://kb.acronis.com/content/1526) webpage at acronis.com. In Acronis True Image 2014 you can create Acronis Bootable Media on a flash drive from within the product with the built-in Acronis Media Builder.

Comment: Yes, it is unnecessary to install CloneZilla to a hard disk unless you are using it as a CloneZilla/DRBL server for taking and storing images. If this is the case then you will need to install DRBL and CloneZilla on a Debian-based OS (probably others, too!)... "CloneZilla Live" is designed to be exactly that... you boot the computer to USB (bypassing your hard disk - i.e. GRUB/Bootloader of your choice) so it means CloneZilla (as said) is a) fast; but also b) means the hard disk being worked on has no resources being used, potentially causing problems. This would also be true of Acronis.

Comment: Okay! So far i must be install Windows and Ubuntu and then install Clonezilla on Ubuntu and boot Acronis from CD.

Comment: [Acronis Forums Creating Acronis BOOT USB disk](https://forum.acronis.com/forum/6294) mentions two methods, the easier of which is using the grub4dos program from Windows. Regarding the other method, I have used the HP USB Disk Storage Format Tool back when it could be downloaded from the official HP website, but now it is no longer available there, so whatever software you can download now that calls itself HP USB Disk Storage Format Tool could be different from the original program.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit unclear, but I'll try and answer regardless;

In order for you to create an Acronis Boot disk, you need to install the ISO onto a hard drive partition, that grub can use as a boot source.

As far as I know, you can't tell grub to boot from an ISO file located inside your other OS partitions.

Usually, I would recommend you burn a CD/DVD with Acronis and/or Clonezilla (so as to not waste hard drive space), but as I understand it, this is not what you're looking for.